# Wildfly Swarm SecurityFraction not present in Arquillian test

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

I have very simply Arquillian test to check if CDI works correct:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.DefaultDeployment;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@DefaultDeployment
public class CDIArquillianTest {

    @Inject
    private SomeClass someclass;

    @Test
    public void testInjection() {
        assertNotNull(someclass);
        assertTrue(someclass.printIt().contains("my string"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCDIContainerPresence() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(CDI.current());
    }
}
```

With very simple class:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeClass {

  public SomeClass(){       
  }

  public String printIt(){
    return "my string";
  }     
}
```

And it works fine when I use bellow pom:

```
 <properties>
    <version.wildfly.swarm>2017.1.1</version.wildfly.swarm>
    <version.wildfly.arquillian>1.1.10.Final</version.wildfly.arquillian>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <solr.version>4.10.3-cdh5.9.0</solr.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.arquillian}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<build>
    <finalName>restful-endpoint</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>package</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <!-- Wildfly Swarm Fractions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.7.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-cdh5.7.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But when I add one additional dependency for ManagementFraction (which I need in other class):

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
       <artifactId>management</artifactId>
    </dependency-->
```

I get bellow error message:

> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001:
>   Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."CDIArquillianTest.jar".WeldStartService:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."CDIArquillianTest.jar".WeldStartService: Failed
>   to start service ... Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException:
>   Type org.wildfly.swarm.security.SecurityFraction not present ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.wildfly.swarm.security.SecurityFraction from [Module
>   "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]

Do I use wrong libs or versions? Is it somehow incompatibile with Arquillian? How can I work it around? I've tried custom Deployment but also failed. Any help is appreciated

Full stack trace (narrowed down):

```
2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.ArquillianArchivePreparer from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadClass(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:65)
...
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.ArquillianArchivePreparer from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
...
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:68)
    ... 13 more

2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) WELD-000142: Exception loading annotated type using ClassFileServices. Falling back to the default implementation. WFLYWELD0050: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonServiceActivator was not found in composite index
2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonServiceActivator because of underlying class loading error: Type org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonServiceActivator from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonServiceActivator from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonServiceActivator from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]

2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000142: Exception loading annotated type using ClassFileServices. Falling back to the default implementation. WFLYWELD0050: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonService was not found in composite index
2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonService because of underlying class loading error: Type org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonService from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonService from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.runtime.DaemonService from [Module "org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian:deployment" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]

2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) WELD-000142: Exception loading annotated type using ClassFileServices. Falling back to the default implementation. WFLYWELD0050: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.deployment.TestableArchiveServiceActivator was not found in composite index
2017-01-11 10:01:05,888 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 3) WELD-000142: Exception loading annotated type using ClassFileServices. Falling back to the default implementation. WFLYWELD0050: org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.deployment.TestableArchiveService was not found in composite index
2017-01-11 10:01:06,053 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.ejb.EJBInjectionEnricher because of underlying class loading error: Type javax.ejb.EJB from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:06,053 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.ejb.EJBInjectionEnricher
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJB
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJB from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]


2017-01-11 10:01:06,128 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 5) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from xxx.ServiceApp because of underlying class loading error: Type org.wildfly.swarm.management.EnhancedSecurityRealm from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:06,128 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 5) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class xxx.ServiceApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/swarm/management/EnhancedSecurityRealm
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.management.EnhancedSecurityRealm from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]

2017-01-11 10:01:06,148 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from xxx.CacheTest2 because of underlying class loading error: Type org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:06,148 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class xxx.CacheTest2
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/swarm/jaxrs/JAXRSArchive
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]

2017-01-11 10:01:06,193 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.protocol.ProtocolRegistryCreator because of underlying class loading error: Type org.jboss.arquillian.config.descriptor.api.ArquillianDescriptor from [Module "org.jboss.arquillian:main" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:06,193 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.protocol.ProtocolRegistryCreator
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/arquillian/config/descriptor/api/ArquillianDescriptor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.arquillian.config.descriptor.api.ArquillianDescriptor from [Module "org.jboss.arquillian:main" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]
...

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wildfly/swarm/jaxrs/JAXRSArchive
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.JAXRSArchive from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]


2017-01-11 10:01:06,223 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000142: Exception loading annotated type using ClassFileServices. Falling back to the default implementation. WFLYWELD0051: Cannot load io.undertow.server.HttpHandler
2017-01-11 10:01:06,223 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.wildfly.swarm.generated.FaviconErrorHandler because of underlying class loading error: Type org.wildfly.swarm.generated.FaviconErrorHandler from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:06,223 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 2) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.generated.FaviconErrorHandler from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.generated.FaviconErrorHandler from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
...
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:68)
    ... 13 more

2017-01-11 10:01:06,258 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.container.ContainerRestarter because of underlying class loading error: Type org.jboss.arquillian.config.descriptor.api.ArquillianDescriptor from [Module "org.jboss.arquillian:main" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
2017-01-11 10:01:06,258 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) Catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Exception while loading class org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.container.ContainerRestarter
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.jboss.arquillian.config.descriptor.api.ArquillianDescriptor not present
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.arquillian.config.descriptor.api.ArquillianDescriptor from [Module "org.jboss.arquillian:main" from BootModuleLoader@436a4e4b for finders [BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap:main), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container:main), ApplicationModuleFinder(swarm.application:main), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@f2f2cc1]]

2017-01-11 10:01:06,298 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 3) WELD-000142: Exception loading annotated type using ClassFileServices. Falling back to the default implementation. WFLYWELD0050: org.wildfly.swarm.cdi.config.deployment.StageConfigBean$1 was not found in composite index

2017-01-11 10:01:06,698 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CDIArquillianTest.jar".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CDIArquillianTest.jar".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.wildfly.swarm.security.SecurityFraction not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.isStaticNestedClass(Reflections.java:402)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.isTopLevelOrStaticNestedClass(Reflections.java:422)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.isTypeManagedBeanOrDecoratorOrInterceptor(Beans.java:507)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:214)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wildfly.swarm.security.SecurityFraction from [Module "deployment.CDIArquillianTest.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 17 more
```

And some more from test result trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inject members
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.enrich(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:78)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
    ...
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException : WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null [Proxied because : Original exception caused: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:364)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectNonContextualInstance(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher.cdi.CDIInjectionEnricher.injectClass(CDIInjectionEnricher.java:125)
    ... 115 more
```

Comment: Is there more stacktrace you can provide?

`management` doesn't depend on `security` so not sure where that's coming from

Comment: More from stacktrace added. If you need complete log than I'd have to send it via email